# c++ looping through files in a directory

Tags: c++

I am not sure if this is possible but is it possible to loop through files in a directory in c++?

For example, how do I know how many files there are in a directory from c++ file and how do I individually call that file instead of manually giving the path to each file which would be extremely painful?

```
while(1){
   pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("getFiles.pcd", *cloud1); <-- each file
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are OS-specific solutions, like

- `opendir` and `readdir` on Linux
- `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` on Windows

or you can use [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration), which has already figured out all the OS-specific bits.